# Reading SAS date values

Tags: sas

My data set has one variable whose values is like MMMYYYY format. But it is in character.

I have used input function to convert it to numeric but it didnt work.
code i have used is

```
newdate=input(chardate, date9.);
```

but is is not working. Please suggest me whats wrong in this code.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

You date isn't in a Date9 format, it's in the MONYY INFORMAT

https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000199690.htm

```
newdate=input(chardate, monyy7.);
```